# ./configure: line 17414: syntax error near unexpected token `libxml2,' on mac(unix)

Tags: macos, unix

I'm trying to compile the "libplist" library as explained in this link: https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libplist. Whenever I try to run the `./autogen.sh` command though I'm told I'm missing the "libxml2" package that is listed as a dependency, as shown by this error: *./configure: line 17414: syntax error near unexpected token `libxml2,'*. I've tried downloading this dependent package multiple times and from multiple sources yet it continues to not recognize that the package is there. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? I'm on a Mac (unix).

Answer (score 1):

libxml2 seems to be missing from your machine and you need to install it. It can easily be done with Homebrew:

```
brew install libxml2
```

Comment: I've tried that, it returns _Warning: libxml2-2.9.2 already installed_ and then still returns the error _./configure: line 17414: syntax error near unexpected token libxml2_ when I run `./autogen.sh`

Comment: Did you try brew doctor?